# Docker: subnet clients can't ping other subnet

Tags: docker, networking

Two containers are created with this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt update && apt upgrade -y && apt install -y vim iputils-ping net-tools tcpdump iproute* iptables traceroute
```

The were created with the following commands in a `Ubuntu 18.04` machine:

```
sudo docker network create --internal --subnet=192.168.2.0/24 netR

sudo docker network create --internal --subnet=172.16.1.0/24 netB1

sudo docker run --name R1_ipsec --hostname R1 --privileged --cap-add=NET_ADMIN --net netR --ip="192.168.2.100" -dit image1
sudo docker run --name R2_ipsec --hostname R2 --privileged --cap-add=NET_ADMIN --net netR --ip="192.168.2.200" -dit image1

sudo docker network connect --ip="172.16.1.254" netR R1

sudo docker run --name PC1_ipsec --hostname PC1_ipsec --privileged --cap-add=NET_ADMIN --net netB1 --ip="172.16.1.2" -dit image1

sudo docker exec PC1 route delete default gw 172.16.1.1

sudo docker exec PC1 route add default gw 172.16.1.254 dev eth0
```

The problem: `PC1` can't ping the `R1`'s interface `192.168.1.100`, even if `R1` have `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`

Doker version: `Docker version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in this line:

```
sudo docker network create --internal --subnet=192.168.2.0/24 netR
```

The `--internal` option makes the network unreachable from other Docker networks.

The solution was to remove this option.